# Pack and Unpack blocks in simulink

Tags: udp, block, simulink, packing

I am trying to setup a UDP communicaion interface between a dspace micro autobox whose communication interface can be played around in simulink and a linux machine where I am receiving/sending packets using julia code. There is this pre-processing that is required to send arrays of doubles over ethernet.

[image]

I wanted to know what the 'pack' and 'unpack' blocks on the dspace side actually do so that I can recreate the same on the linux machine side to decode the data sent over the lan.

Comment: Can you confirm which library these Pack and Unpack block come from? And show us the dialog parameters of the blocks?

Comment: I think the following link has the functions that does the intended jobs (https://www.mathworks.com/examples/matlab-communications/4726-codegen-of-pack-and-unpack-example ) and the toolbox with these blocks is (http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/50696-pack-and-unpack-data)

Answer (score 0):

The pack and unpack functions can be done in python using the [struct](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html) module in python. The following are the functions that did the same job as pack and unpack blocks in the simulink (dspace) side. Note: dspace processor is big endian which explains the change endianess blocks

Sample code:

```
 import struct as st

def pack_unpack_receive(X,len_data):
    packed_Uint8 = st.pack('B'*len(X),*X)
    unpacked_double = st.unpack('d'*len_data, packed_Uint8)
    return unpacked_double

def pack_unpack_send(X):
    packed_double = st.pack('d'*len(X),*X)
    unpacked_Uint8 = st.unpack('B'*len(X)*8,packed_double)
    return unpacked_double
```